# Flutter: Every flutter command gives this error

Tags: flutter, dart

Every flutter command gives this error:

Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.5.0.

Because flutter_tools requires SDK version >=2.7.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...

Not able to run a single flutter command, what's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix `environment`: in `pubspec.yaml` to allow the Dart SDK version you are using (the one from Flutter)

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

### OR

First Make sure you have a working internet connection and if this issue still exists then, this error may be because the dart sdk may have not been properly downloaded. The simplest solution is to delete the cache folder located in flutter/bin(location where flutter is installed) and then Run flutter doctor

1. Check if you are connected to the internet and because flutter needs to IDE needs to download some dependencies and load them when the IDE starts.
2. Disable your Anti Virus because it stops flutter doing `Flutter Upgrade`, once you are down check if there's an issue with your `Flutter Doctor`.
3. Delete the cache folder which is located inside

> flutter/bin

(where flutter is installed) and then Run `Flutter Doctor`

4. Last option would be to delete your Flutter SDK and download a new one, with your you can know who was the culprit who stopped your projects from running.

Comment: Let me know if this fixes the issue. I think it will. Let's hope

Comment: This issue is for every project. So, do I need to change environment for every pubspec file?

Comment: if the issue with every flutter project than there is an issue with ur Flutter SDK

Comment: Yes actually, I reinstalled Flutter and everything is working fine now. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.4.
Because image_editor_pro >=1.0.7 depends on cupertino_icons >=1.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, image_editor_pro >=1.0.7 is forbidden.
And because image_editor_pro <1.0.7 depends on cupertino_icons ^0.1.2, every version of image_editor_pro requires cupertino_icons ^0.1.2.
So, because memeistan depends on both cupertino_icons ^1.0.0 and image_editor_pro ^1.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because memeistan depends on both cupertino_icons ^1.0.0 and image_editor_pro ^1.0.0, version solving failed.) i am facing this

Comment: @MuhammadAnus flutter upgrade (with flutter upgrade your SDK version will be from 2.10.4 to 1.22.5(latest in 2020 January) and then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling flutter sdk works!