# Every time I open Flutter project "Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)"

Tags: flutter, upgrade, flutter-doctor

Every time I open my flutter projects I get this error: "Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)"

I am using a MacBook Air M1 Ventura 13.1

I know that I have to delete the cache folder in flutter and run flutter doctor, but I have to do this every time after I shut down my computer.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to manually upgrade flutter using `flutter upgrade`. This might resolve dependency conflicts that are preventing the automatic upgrade.
2. Clean and repair the cache:
   `flutter clean`
   `flutter pub cache repair`
   The cache sometimes gets corrupted or contains outdated resources.
3. Reinstall Flutter if none of the above solutions work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried all of your methods, but still have to do it every time I open Visual Studio.

Comment: Try to delete the cache folder located in flutter/bin directory, and then run flutter pub cache repair again. Then try to run flutter doctor and see the output.

Comment: Otherwise, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64297668/7156819